# WPF datagrid one column as Combobox add each row different list

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I have datagrid wpf and one column is as combobox. For each row I need different item list.
I have this structure

```
public class DuplicateType:List<string>
{
    public string d { get; set; }
}

public class StructurDatLegend : ObservableObject
{
    public bool selected { get; set; }
    public string VName { get; set; }
    public View VLeg { get; set; }
    public XYZ VPol { get; set; }
    public  DuplicateType DuplicateT { get; set; }
}

foreach (Tuple<View, XYZ> LegItem in duplicatesheet.Getlegendcollection(vs))
{
    DuplicateType o = new DuplicateType();
    o.Add("tee");
    o.Add("fdvxvx");  
    Legend.Add(new StructurDatLegend { selected = false, VName = LegItem.Item1.Name, VLeg = LegItem.Item1, VPol = LegItem.Item2 , DuplicateT = o });
}
```

How can I load this data in xaml code?  This code doesn't work

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header =" Duplicate" Width="100" x:Name="DuplicateType" DisplayMemberPath="d"  SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Path= DuplicateT}" SelectedValuePath="{Binding DuplicateT}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry because my English. Did you set DataContext for datagrid? In your xaml code, you set `DisplayMemberPath="d"` but in behind code `d` not be set.